# Is there key infrastructure allows one running as sudo remotely without prompting password?

Tags: sudo

For example, I can use `ssh-id-copy` to get the key and login to the remote server without entering the password.
Is there a similar mechanism to run as root without prompting password?

I don't know. If login with a key is sort of safe, then I argue there should be a mechanism like that for `sudo`. `NOPASSWD` is not a good solution, however.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have key infrastructure for this. You can use sudoer instead.

Create a file in /etc/sudoers.d with

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/filename
```

add a line begin with your account

```
ubuntuman ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

save the file

use it with caution

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> NOPASSWD is not a good solution

But `NOPASSWD` is *the* solution. Can you clarify your question to explain what you don't like about it?

There is a separation of concerns here: authentication is separated from authorization. Once you have proved to the system that you are *who* you say you are (by logging in), `sudo` is responsible for restricting *what* you can do.

The `sudoers` file syntax is pretty sophisticated (if somewhat arcane). You can restrict individual users (or groups of users) to certain sets of commands, with or without passwords. Would that help alleviate your concerns?